# Converting Makefile to CMake with local includes and libs

Tags: gcc, cmake, makefile

I am unsure of how to add my include and libs files to a cmake file. I keep seeing references to several methods that I do not understand when trying to figure this out. I need to get my /include and /lib directories into CMake properly so I can use them in my code. What is the proper way of adding libraries to CMake?

```
OBJS = simple.o 
INCLUDES = -I../../include
LIBS = -L../../lib
LDFLAGS = -lglad -lglfw3 
PROGRAM = simple
CFLAGS = -g
COMPILER = g++

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)     # is Windows_NT on XP, 2000, 7, Vista, 10...
    LDFLAGS += -lopengl32 -lgdi32
    PROGRAM :=$(addsuffix .exe,$(PROGRAM))
else ifeq ($(shell uname -s),Darwin)     # is MACOSX
    LDFLAGS += -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit
endif

simple: clean $(OBJS)
    $(COMPILER) -o $(PROGRAM) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) $(LDFLAGS)

simple.o: simple.c
    $(COMPILER) $(INCLUDES) $(CFLAGS) -c simple.c
    
RM = rm -f
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)     # is Windows_NT on XP, 2000, 7, Vista, 10...
    RM := del
endif

clean: 
    $(RM) $(OBJS) $(PROGRAM)
```

This is all I've got so far:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(hw2)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_library(bar SHARED IMPORTED)

add_executable(hw2 main.cpp)
```

Comment: @user I am not asking for language translation, I'm asking how to include my INCLUDES and LIBS directory into my CMAKE. That's all I want to know.

Answer (score 0):

A simple example for you:

The files in this example are below:

```
tree
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── include
│   └── shared
│       └── Hello.h
└── src
    ├── Hello.cpp
    └── main.cpp
```

- CMakeLists.txt[] - Contains the CMake commands you wish to run
- include/shared/Hello.h[] - The header file to include
- src/Hello.cpp[] - A source file to compile
- src/main.cpp[] - The source file with main

STEP 1: Specify the minimum version of CMake  and create a project

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)    
project(hello_library)
```

STEP 2: Add a Shared Library using **[add_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html?highlight=add_library)**

```
add_library(hello_library SHARED 
    src/Hello.cpp
)
```

STEP 3: Set the directories that should be included using [**target_include_directories**](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html?highlight=target_include_directories)

```
target_include_directories(hello_library
    PUBLIC 
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)
```

STEP 4: Add an executable

```
add_executable(hello_binary
    src/main.cpp
)
```

STEP 5: Link a Shared Library using **[target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html?highlight=target_link_libraries)**

```
target_link_libraries( hello_binary
    PRIVATE 
        hello_library
)
```

Comment: if you are using Windows, add `set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)` commond following `project` commond.